# RestResource GET with multiple parameters

Tags: apex, restresource

In Apex RestResource What is the correct format for urlMapping when you want to pass in multiple parameters in a GET request?
So I need to pass in accountId and serviceId as filters to GET.

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/Revenues/accountId={acctId}&serviceId={svcId}');
```

OR

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/Revenues/accountId/*/serviceId/*');
```

I am confused.
I tried to use the first one and then get the parameterss using 
request.params.get('accountId'); but just get NULL.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

HTTP GET defines data as a series of query parameters in the URI itself. For example, here’s a URI:

```
https://na8.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/FieldCase?companyName=GenePoint
```

So your code will be like

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/Revenues/*)
@HttpGet
  global static List<Case> getOpenCases() {
    String accountId = RestContext.request.params.get('accountId');
    String accountId = RestContext.request.params.get('serviceId');
```

[Creating REST APIs using Apex REST](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Creating_REST_APIs_using_Apex_REST)

Or you can parse the URl as well

```
@HttpGet
    global static Account doGet() {
        RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
        RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
        String accountId = req.requestURI.substring(req.requestURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
```

[Apex REST Basic Code Sample](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_rest_code_sample_basic.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, and it's Salesforce's fault, I think the answers to your question are going to suck.

You SHOULD be able to do this:

@RestResource(urlMapping='/Revenues/account/{accountId}/service/{serviceId}');

... but the Apex annotation doesn't let you. It'd be neat though, right?

The "accepted" answer is as close as you're gonna get. For the parse-based method, perhaps a Regex-based mechanism (helper method) could more easily pull out those IDs from a well-formed URI? I.e. given a Dictionary with keys and empty values, and a URI, pull out the values?

It may seem overly-complicated, but if you start writing lots of APIs, the copy-pasting of the same Substring/LastIndexOf code over and over it going to feel tedious.

Comment: If your code is feeling repetitive and tedious, you should have written a utility long ago.

Comment: And yet, the route pattern I declared it should be, is straight out of Java and .NET. One should not have to write a utility, because the problem should not exist. And if they followed a RegEx way, then surely it'd be in a helper/utility (because who wouldn't do that?!)